# how to replace this code snippet to not use attrs? react and emotion/styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion

I'm creating a checkbox component in react and using styled components, how can I replace this code to not use attrs?

```
export const HiddenCheckbox = styled.input.attrs({type: 'checkbox'})`
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
`;
```

my main:

```
return (
    <CheckboxContainer checked={checked} onClick={handleCheckboxChange}>
      <HiddenCheckbox onChange={handleCheckboxChange} checked={checked}/>
      <StyledCheckbox checked={checked}>
        <Icon/>
      </StyledCheckbox>
      <Text checked={checked}>{children}</Text>
    </CheckboxContainer>
);
```

Comment: so you want to remove the type argument of HiddenCheckbox?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying additional props with attrs, you can directly add the props to the component while rendering

```
export const HiddenCheckbox = styled.input`
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
`;

return (
    <CheckboxContainer checked={checked} onClick={handleCheckboxChange}>
      <HiddenCheckbox type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckboxChange} checked={checked}/>
      <StyledCheckbox checked={checked}>
        <Icon/>
      </StyledCheckbox>
      <Text checked={checked}>{children}</Text>
    </CheckboxContainer>
);
```